# Node not executing request inside a request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, loopbackjs

I tried to run this code:

```
app.delete('/closeTrelloBoard', function (req, res) {
    console.log('[data], [...]');
    var options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.trello.com/1/members/someId/boards?key=KEY&token=TOKEN'
    };

    request(options, function (error, body) {
        var boards = JSON.parse(body.body);

        for (var i=0; i<boards.length; i++) {
            console.log(boards[i].id);  //This line runs
            app.put('/closeTrelloBoard',function (req, res) {

                var options = {
                    method: 'PUT',
                    url: 'https://api.trello.com/1/boards/'+boards[i].id+'/closed?key=KEY&token=TOKEN&value=true',
                };

                request(options, function (error,body) {
                    console.log('Board closed');  //But this line not runs
                });
            });
        };

    });
});
```

In the code above I have tried to make a request in another request callback. The problem is that first request gave me proper response but the second request was not giving me any output.

Please guide me why second request not running.

Answer (score 0):

Your second request is set in a callback to [`app.put()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.put.method) method. It means that request will be fired only when `/closeTrelloBoard` route will be called (It doesn't seem logic to set a route in a callback to request, even worse - in a loop). So, in order to run second request after first is done, call it just before `app.put()` method. I don't know your intentions, and I can be mistaken, but I guess that `app.put()` should be set somewhere in other pat of the code.

```
app.delete('/closeTrelloBoard', function (req, res) {
console.log('[data], [...]');
var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.trello.com/1/members/someId/boards?key=KEY&token=TOKEN'
};

request(options, function (error, body) {
    var boards = JSON.parse(body.body);

    for (var i=0; i<boards.length; i++) {
        console.log(boards[i].id);  //This line runs
        var options = {
            method: 'PUT',
            url: 'https://api.trello.com/1/boards/'+boards[i].id+'/closed?key=KEY&token=TOKEN&value=true',
        };

        request(options, function (error,body) {
            console.log('Board closed');  //But this line not runs
        });

    };
    app.put('/closeTrelloBoard',function (req, res) {


    });
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, I don't really understand what you are trying to do... By the tags I can see you are using ExpressJS, so "app" is the convention for his main var...

Now, what I can read from the code, is:
You are registering a "DELETE" method to "/closeTrelloBoard", then, you create an object called "options" to pass to the request, and you make the request... Ok, now you parse de JSON from the body of the request and... make a loop to make requests... ok this is the first I see, try to use Callbacks instead of loops, because is the power of Node. Lets keep going. Now... I don't understand, you are registering, "PUT" methods for the "/closeTrelloBoard"... I think this isn't has to be there... and then you make the request of the Loop...

Lets see if this can work, this should be the "NodeJS way", If you have doubts just ask them :) I don't remember how this callbacks methods are called, But I remember they have its own name, also I haven't tried it, so... It couldn't work:

```
app.delete('/closeTrelloBoard', function (req, res) {
    console.log('[data], [...]');
    var options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.trello.com/1/members/someId/boards?key=KEY&token=TOKEN'
    };

    request(options, function (error, body) {
        var boards = JSON.parse(body.body);

        loopEveryBoard = function(i, next){
            if (i >= boards.length){
                next()
            } else {
                var options = {
                    method: 'PUT',
                    url: 'https://api.trello.com/1/boards/'+boards[i].id+'/closed?key=KEY&token=TOKEN&value=true',
                };

                request(options, function (error,body) {
                    console.log('Board ' + i + ' closed');  //But this line not runs
                    loopEveryBoard(++i, next); // The ++ has to be on the left to make it effective before the function takes the value
                });
            }
        }

        loopEveryBoard(0, function(){
            console.log('Every board closed');
        });

    });
});
```